# desktop app with HTML5 interface

Tags: html, desktop

I want to create quite robust desktop app, which will do some basic file analysis (e.g. I need to list all files in directory) and will do some basic visualization of data. I want to use also part of the visualization online (same component).
It would be the best to make a HTML5 interface and use it for both. What is the best way how to do it? I think it is possible to make it via localhost (e.g. Apatch), but is it than possible to make some one click instalation? (I wnat to make it for dummies :) ).
Thx

Answer (score 2):

try [appcelerator titanium desktop edition](http://www.appcelerator.com)